# Passport.js on Cloud Functions for Firebase gives error "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, passport.js, google-cloud-functions

I have been trying to integrate Passport.js Gitlab oAuth on Firebase cloud functions for the passed couple of days. I'm getting an error that is difficult to debug. Can you please help me understand what is actually failing and how can I fix it ?

```
Error : 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:639:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:610:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:582:5)
```

This is the entire function. The passport library being used is https://github.com/gtanner/passport-gitlab

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
// Firebase Setup
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const passport = require('passport');

const session = require('express-session');

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true
});


const router = new express.Router();
router.use(cors);



const FirebaseStore = require('connect-session-firebase')(session);

const GitLabStrategy = require('passport-gitlab').Strategy;


const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: `https://${process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT}.firebaseio.com`
});




router.use(session({
    store: new FirebaseStore({
        database: admin.database(),
    }),
    secret: 'myapp',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.session());



passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serialize', user);
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    console.log('deserialize', obj);
    done(null, obj);
});




passport.use(new GitLabStrategy({
        clientID: '',
        clientSecret: '',
        callbackURL: "https://us-central1-auth-fa8a7.asd.net/api/gitlabCallback"
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
        console.log('accessToken ', accessToken)
        console.log('refreshToken ', refreshToken)
        console.log('refreshToken ', profile)

        cb(null, profile);
    }
));




router.get('/gitlab', passport.authenticate('gitlab'));
router.get('/gitlabCallback', passport.authenticate('gitlab', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));



exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(router);
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, I resolved it by initializing router as

```
const router = new express();
```

rather than

```
const router = new express.Router();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Function's logs are not always reliable. I faced the same issue and while debugging found that the error was due to undefined variables. Had a `json` which was not defined and was trying to access the keys of the undefined json. I would recommend to check this way.